# How Can I create simultaneous carousels

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i.e. two carousels in the same location but one is always hidden, with two buttons (anchors?) above to turn either one on:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div id="floorsCarousel" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/1/" alt="Chania">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/2/" alt="Chania">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/3/" alt="Flower">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/4/" alt="Flower">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My JS does not appear to be working, this is what I have in my JS file:

```
var floorsCarousel = document.getElementById("floorsCarousel");
    var spaceCarousel = document.getElementById("spaceCarousel");

    function floorPlans() {
        if (floorsCarousel.style.display==="none") {
            floorsCarousel.style.display="inherit";
        }
        if (spaceCarousel.style.display!=="none") {
            spaceCarousel.style.display="none";
        }
        return false;
    }

    function spacePlans() {
        if (spaceCarousel.style.display==="none") {
            spaceCarousel.style.display="inherit";
        }
        if (floorsCarousel.style.display!=="none") {
            floorsCarousel.style.display="none";
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/fat4vjgw/)

Comment: initialise what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution for you that does what you need [here](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/dkv1m0q3/). I've created "buttons" to toggle which carousel you wish to open and wrapped the carousel's in a div with the attr's `id="Car-#" class="Car-toggle"`

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
    <button class="toggleCar" data-for="Car-1">Toggle 1</button>
    <button class="toggleCar" data-for="Car-2">Toggle 2</button>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="Car-1" class="Car-toggle">carousel One
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div id="floorsCarousel" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/1/" alt="Chania">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/2/" alt="Chania">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/3/" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/4/" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Car-2" class="Car-toggle">carousel Two
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div id="floorsCarousel" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/1/" alt="Chania">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/2/" alt="Chania">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/3/" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/600/sports/4/" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript (JQuery since your using bootstrap)**

```
$('.toggleCar').click(function(){
var CarWrapperName=$(this).attr('data-for');
    $('.Car-toggle').hide();
    $('#'+CarWrapperName).show();
});

//Hide All Toggles and Show Default
$('.Car-toggle').hide();
$('#Car-1').show();
```

Comment: Why not? Whats the problem with it?